# Disk partition Centos7 LVM

Tags: linux, centos, lvm

I have a small VPS (Centos 7) that I am currently working on and want to publish some websites.

Want to partition a part of the disk so I can put the `/var/tmp` and `/tmp` so I can apply the `noexec` and the other rules as advised. The output of the `fdisk -l` is the following:

```
[root@vps59119 ~]# fdisk -l
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental 
phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/ploop20162: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: 86EB4992-47F0-42D4-98BB-81D8A91A0DFB


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048    104855552     50G  Linux filesyste
```

The output of `df -h | grep ^/dev` is the following:

```
[root@vps59119 ~]# df -h | grep ^/dev
/dev/ploop20162p1   50G  901M   47G   2% /
```

As I understanf is that I have only 1 big partition of the disk (`/`) under PV `/dev/ploop20162p1`

When I try to partition that space executing `fdisk /dev/ploop20162p1` and creating a new partition I get the following error.

```
[root@vps59119 ~]# fdisk /dev/ploop20162p1
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.23.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table
Building a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xfabde285.

Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 1
First sector (2048-104853504, default 2048):
Using default value 2048
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (2048-104853504, default 104853504): +5G
Partition 1 of type Linux and of size 5 GiB is set

Command (m for help): w
fdisk: cannot write disk label: Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: What is the output of `uname -r`?

Comment: This is what I see when I run that     
   `3.10.0`

Comment: That’s it?  There should be more. Anyway, it isn’t a CentOS kernel. Is the a VPS that uses Virtuozzo containers?

Comment: I don't know that exactly. I guess that's the reason why I can't partition my machine. I could be kind of a container container and I don't have real access to the hardware

Comment: It looks like you tried to create a partition within a partition. That's possible, but it complicates things. Try creating a partition on the "disk" instead: /dev/ploop20162

Comment: How do you suggest I do that? I don't have access to the initial installation of centos. I can't create partitions of the boot disk during the setup